# java android AsyncHttpClient send get request with header and parameters

Tags: java, android

I need to send this to server :

```
Authorization SCToken 282518f3-95b90c08-9453-4cce-9a73-eb80cb7f86e1 this send like a HEADER
```

and this

```
modify_after 2017-06-09T11:06:37Z like a QUERY
```

I did this:

```
public void getUpdate(String token , String lastModify, AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler){
    syncHttpClient = new SyncHttpClient();
    client.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    syncHttpClient.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    BasicHeader[] headers = new BasicHeader[]{new    BasicHeader("Authorization", "SCToken " + token)};
    Log.e("get ", token + "   , " + getAbsoluteUrl("last_state/?modify_after=" + lastModify));
    syncHttpClient.get(context, getAbsoluteUrl("last_state/?modify_after=" + lastModify), headers, null, handler);
}
```

but as the answer from the server I get failure and a status is a 404.

Comment: 404 HTTP error occurs when you try to connect to a non-existing website... Did you put the URL in your code correctly?

Comment: There must be some valid URL, you have just used some part of URL which results in 404.

Comment: Have you verified with tools like postman the effective working of the server?

Comment: @Geryson @ Thecave3  Yes I add one more char thanks for help